# Some questions about the onsen-ui

Tags: angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I'm fairly new in the use of Onsen and before starting I would like to address some questions.

- You can load separate files as template? 
     - index.html 
     - - Page1.html 
     - - Page2.html
- You can work with routes angularjs?
- It is possible to redirect the logged in user to a specific page?

Hugs and thanks for listening.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can use both separated and combined templates.
2. No. At least the current Onsen UI does not support AngularJS route.
3. What situation do you consider? In the mobile application case, back to application
   from web login page is impossible. In such case, you should use InAppBrowser.